# Show that two sums have the same distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, characteristic-functions

I have not been able to show that the following two stochastic variables have the same distribution. My question is as follows:

Let
$$
X_1, X_2,..., X_n 
$$
be independent and identically distributed. Furthermore,
$$
a_1, a_2,...,a_n
$$
are arbitrary real numbers. Set
$$
Y_1 = a_1X_1 + a_2X_2 + .... +a_nX_n
$$
$$
Y_2 = a_nX_1 + a_{n-1}X_2+....+a_1X_n
$$

Show that
$$y_1 \stackrel {d}{=} y_2
$$

I have tried proving this using the definition of the characteristic function
$$
\varphi_{Y_1}(t) = E[e^{itY_1}]=E[e^{it(a_1X_1+a_2X_2+...+a_nX_n)}]
$$
$$
\varphi_{Y_2}(t) = E[e^{itY_2}]=E[e^{it(a_nX_1 + a_{n-1}X_2+....+a_1X_n)}]
$$

but I can't continue from here. Is this a correct approach to proving the above? Furthermore, the question says nothing about the quantity of a's.

(If we, for instance, would have known that n is large, we could have used the Central Limit Theorem which would say that the distribution of Xk approaches a normal distribution, and then used the characteristic function of a normal distribution to prove that Y1 have the same distribution as Y2. But there is no such information in the question. Do I have to assume this to be able to solve the question?)

Thank you!
Jam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $(X_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}$ is i.i.d. then $(Y_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}$ defined by $Y_k=X_{n+1-k}$ for every $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$ is distributed like $(X_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}$, in particular, $a_1X_1+a_2X_2+\cdots+a_nX_n$ and $a_1Y_1+a_2Y_2+\cdots+a_nY_n$ are identically distributed.